# how to enable gzip in an angular cli project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to implement compression and then have nginx serve up the compressed files without doing the compression on the fly. I haven't been able to figure out a way to get gzipping into an angular cli project. I was thinking about a separate webpack config and looping over the different bundles but that seemed like it would be introducing unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Compression Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/compression-webpack-plugin). To chane the webpack config inside the Angular CLI, however, you'd have to do [`ng eject`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) first. Keep in mind that this action is irrevesable.

Comment: This was my first idea and one that would work obviously, but is there no other way without ng eject?

Comment: I guess you could always create a custom script to do this?

Comment: Yeah I'm leaning more and more towards a separate webpack config I guess